# Granting Azure SQL MI -> AD read permissions fails with error 400, Invalid object identifier 'null' - any ideas?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a new Azure AD

I've switched my subscription over to it

I created a SQL Server managed instance

I went to the SQL Server MI, and to the active directory admin section of the MI.

I attempted to grant read permissions to the AD via the "click here to grand read permissions link"

I received the following error
[image]

Any clues?

Comment: May I know what is the authentication method selected by you while creating the SQL MI?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT  I left nearly everything as default, except the cores/ram, and made it a public endpoint. Don't remember being asked much about authentication except I think I saw it had a system assigned identity, and that's what the MI says it has. No databases have been created yet.

Comment: Could you please try logging in to portal from incognito browser and see if you are able to add? and also may I know  If you have created SQL MI first in that subscription then attached the azure ad to subscription or vice-versa?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT logging in to a private window (and passing my company's MFA) then made it work. Write that as the answer and I'll accept it. I created the AD, switched subscription to the AD, then created the MI. Earlier, I had previously tried to move an existing MI from the old AD to new AD, and failed, so deleted it (test db), and created a new MI as described.

Comment: Glad to be of Help @GilesDMiddleton !! Added the same as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While clicking on the `Grant permissions` it should automatically take the User objectId who has logged in to the portal and check the permissions for the user if the user has `Global administrator` / `Directory Reader role(Preview)` in the Tenant Or Subscription and finally will perform the operation.

But as you have created a new AD tenant and added it to the subscription it sometimes fails to sync (tenant and subscription) and as per the error `Invalid object Identifier null` it fails to get the user details .

So, the Issue can be fixed by logging in to the portal from a private window of the browser or signing out of the portal,then clearing the cache of the browser and relogging.